# Debug in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, css, debugging, cordova

i'm a newbie for phonegap so before starting my project i learnt html, css and javascript basics, created a sample project for practise but not able to debug my code so went though google for a solution and found this link `http://debug.phonegap.com/` after pasting this bit of code `<script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>` in index.html and clicked all button at the bottom, now i could not find any debug error message in the column.. i'm i going in a right way? please help me.